# How can I bind the event to the function callback or any alternative solution?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm creating a library web app with React, the idea of the app is to categorize books into shelves (Want to Read ,Currently Reading shelf, Read shelf, none) using a select button on each book component, there are two issues so far, first: can't bind the event to the function callback and can't store the book element in a useState hook array to use its props such as id in categorizing books into shelves.
[The Error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X03p5.png)

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { getAll, search, get, update, api } from "./../BooksAPI";
function Book(props) {
  const [currState, setCurrState] = useState({
    shelf: [],
    book: [],
  });

  const updatingBooks = async function (event) {
    const shelf = event.target.value;
    const book = event.target.closest(".book");
    const { id } = book;

    setCurrState(() => {
      return currState.shelf.push(shelf);
    });
    setCurrState(() => {
      return currState.book.push(book);
    });

    await update(currState.shelf, currState.book);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    updatingBooks();

    console.log(currState.shelf, currState.book);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(currState.shelf, currState.book);
  }, [currState.shelf, currState.book]);

  return (
    <div className="book" id={props.id}>
      <div className="book-top">
        <div
          className="book-cover"
          style={{
            width: 128,
            height: 193,

            backgroundImage: `url(${props.url})`,
          }}
        />
        <div className="book-shelf-changer">
          <select onChange={updatingBooks}>
            <option value="move" disabled>
              Move to...
            </option>
            <option value="wantToRead">Want to Read</option>
            <option value="currentlyReading">Currently Reading</option>
            <option value="read">Read</option>
            <option value="none">None</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="book-title">{props.title}</div>
      <div className="book-authors">{props.authors}</div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Book;
```

Comment: Your `updatingBooks` takes an `event` object and you are not providing one in `useEffect`

Comment: I know, that's exactly my question, what should I do ?

Comment: Remove that `useEffect`

Comment: And how the component is going to update after every change ?

Comment: since selecting with trigger state change, component will re-render automatically